# "Minority" vs "Marginalized" group

Tags: american-english, political-correctness

Today, we were having a group discussion in my workplace. There was a part where we all were given a chance to explain how the recent election affected us. During my turn, I referred myself (Asian American) as a part of a "minority" group. Later, our supervisor encouraged the use of "marginalized" instead of "minority".

However, doesn't "marginalized" suggest that the group is being discriminated even though I just want to mean that the group has a smaller population. Which word makes more sense in this context?

Comment: "Social exclusion, or social marginalization, is the social disadvantage and relegation to the fringe of society." If you feel you have been _relegated_ and _excluded_, it would work; otherwise, "minority" is probably better. It sounds like your supervisor was trying to politicize the discussion towards a certain direction.

Comment: This sounds like office nonsense to me.  *Minority* does not imply *marginalized* anymore than the converse.

Comment: So that you don't end up marginalized, in addition to being in the minority (racially and also in terms of your opinion about these words), you might want to keep your views about your supervisor's vocabulary to yourself....  "Awkward Black Girl" shows, with humor,  the importance of being circumspect in the workplace, especially when talking about race and ethnicity....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Minority and marginalized are semantically unrelated.**

Minority means you are a small fraction of the population. Marginalized means you are on the fringes of society, excluded or isolated. The two may often be true of the same group but don't have to be.

For example, whites in Apartheid South Africa were a minority but not marginalized. Rural poor in China might be marginalized but not a minority.

Which you use depends on what you mean.

Comment: True.  In the US, if you are a member of the minority known as "the 1%", you are far from "marginalized".